# Facing issue with Non interactive Sitecore CLI 5+

Tags: sitecore-cli

I am facing issue while configuring non interactive mode of login for pre-prod environments.

Please let me know the exact steps to do that.

[image]

[image]

And also, how to configure sitecore CLI in azure?

Comment: Have you configured Identity Server to allow this "SitecoreCLIServer" client?

Comment: I just added client id and secret to Sitecore.IdentityServer.DevEx.xml and its working now. Thanks @MichaelWest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the `client id` and `client secret` in the Identity server `~/Config/Sitecore.IdentityServer.DevEx.xml` resolved my issue.